# Troubleshooting Windows BSOD that tells me "The driver is mismanaging system PTEs"

Tags: windows-xp, dell, bsod

I recently moved a hard drive from a Dell Optiplex 760 mini-tower to a 760 small form factor.  All seemed OK until I attempted to remote desktop into it and recieved a blue screen of death stating that:

```
The driver is mismanaging system PTEs.
```

The STOP information:

```
STOP: 0xDA ( 0x400, 0xFFFFFADF2A6CC000, 0x200, 0x0)
```

The OS is Windows XP x64 SP2.  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: I have not seen that specifically. Have you tried running the dump (if one was created) through the NT Debugging tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do they have the same onboard video card? It looks like the Optiplex 760 can come with 7 different possible video cards. If they are different and using the wrong driver it will cause the 0xDA BSOD, which relates to virtual memory being too heavily used (unlikely) or a bad system driver (more likely).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it turned out to be the video drivers.  The old system had an ATI 1600 in it, and the new system does not.  Once I uninstalled all of the ATI tools, things went back to normal.

Comment: looks like iainlbc beat me to it!